# What is difference between MFT and WMQ

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

Can any one explain about MFT and what is the difference between MFT and Websphere MQ. And why we need MFT even we have MQ.

Answer (score 4):

WebSphere MQ MFT (or Managed File Transfer) is a extra, chargable component of WebSphere MQ that allows you to send/receive files between your systems in a managed and auditable way, regardless of file size or the operating systems used. It uses your WebSphere MQ network to do this.

WebSphere MQ MFT supersedes the WebSphere MQ File Transfer Edition (FTE) product.

Rather than me type all about it here, you should read the "Product overview" section in the WebSphere MQ Knowledge Center for the MFT component:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/wmqfte_intro.htm?cp=SSFKSJ_8.0.0%2F2

If you don't want to, or don't have the need to, transfer files over your WebSphere MQ network, you don't need to use MFT.